# Mandate array key in method parameter

Tags: php

So I have a method inside my class which will create a new prospect, which has a `$fields` parameter that users can pass in the fields.

So let's say that I have the following format:

```
$new_pardot = new FH_Pardot();
$new_pardot->create_prospect();
```

The `create_prospect()` method has `$fields` param that needs a array passed into it, so an example would be like this:

```
$new_pardot->create_prospect([
    'email' => $posted_data['email'], // Make key mandatory or throw error on method.
    'firstName' => $posted_data['first-name'],
    'lastName' => $posted_data['last-name'],
]);
```

Is there a way to make the `email` key in the `$fields` mandatory? Users will need to pass in the `email` key, but then they have the option to pass in additional keys as shown above.

Here is the example method:

```
public function create_prospect(array $fields)
{
    // Other logic in here.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take one of many approaches to *where* the validation takes place. The two obvious ways are doing the validation *within* the `create_prospect` function, or doing the validation *before/outside* calling `create_prospect`.

The traditional approach is to do your validation before trying to create the entity. It makes collecting and displaying validation errors easier than throwing validation messages from various places.

### within

```php
public function create_prospect(array $fields)
{
    if (!isset($fields['email']) {
        throw new ValidationException('Please provide an email');     
    }

    ... carry on with your work
}
```

### Before/Outside

```php
$fields = [
    'email' => $posted_data['email'],
    'firstName' => $posted_data['first-name'],
    'lastName' => $posted_data['last-name'],
];

if (!isset($fields['email']) {
    throw new ValidationException('Please provide an email');     
}

$new_pardot = new FH_Pardot();
$new_pardot->create_prospect($fields);
```

Comment: Thanks @waterloomatt, this is a new approach that I wasn't familiar with, this looks great!

Answer (score 1):

you should create a validation for your `$posted_data['email'].` and check it to be required.
but if you want this format you may try to ways :

1- use separate argument for email:

```
public function create_prospect($email,array $fields)
{
    // Other logic in here.
}
```

2- **better way** is to check the email field in your array, with or without an external function :

```
public function create_prospect(array $fields)
{
    if(!array_key_exists("email", $fields)){
        // printing error! => echo 'error' or throw an exception
        return;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the second option works just enough for what I need.